# label doesn't work, I tried my best

Tags: java, label, binary-search, goto

I tried continue & break labels in java but it throw errors.

Here is the code:

```
private int search(int[] seq, int key, int low, int high){
    int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
    out :  //label
    if (key == mid) {
        return mid;
    }
    if (key <  mid) {
        high = mid;
        if (key != mid) {
            break out;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code in your question for future readers, in case the link to that image no longer works.

Comment: Post code not pictures. I, for one, prefer not to navigate to random Imgur links posted by new users.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Ok guys I copied it.

Comment: @nickzoum good work; thanks.

Comment: You can only break out of a scope you are in and you can only continue a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Labelled `break`* works only with cycles. 
And beware, they are **not** equivalent with `goto` because they *transfer the control **to the next statement** after the break-ed cycle*.

Here an example copied from the [language basics tutorial - break statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) on Oracle's site (I'm too lazy to be original if other good examples are available):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] arrayOfInts = { 
            { 32, 87, 3, 589 },
            { 12, 1076, 2000, 8 },
            { 622, 127, 77, 955 }
        };
        int searchfor = 12;

        int i;
        int j = 0;
        boolean foundIt = false;

    search:
        for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length;j++) {
                if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor) {
                    foundIt = true;
                    break search;
                }
            }
        }

        if (foundIt) // etc
    }
}
```

---

Just in case you are interested more on how to solve the binary search than how to use `break`ing to labels. The code below has the same performance as one that would use goto's (if they'd actually exist in java).

```
private static int search(int[] seq, int key, int low, int high) {

    while (low <= high) {
        // this is as good as low+(high-low)/2. 
        int mid = (low + high) >>> 1; // this is (low+high)/2

        int midVal = seq[mid];

        if (midVal < key) {
            low = mid + 1;
        }
        else if (midVal > key) {
            high = mid - 1;
        }
        else {
            // why break when you can return?
            return mid; // key found
        }
    }
    // key not found. Return the 2's complement of the insert position:
    // that is -(insertPosition+1)
    return -(low + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Labels are to be used with loops if you have 3 loops and you need to call break; in the innermost loop, you would then use a label to break to the outer loop because if you just call break; it will break the innermost and go to the middle loop. Your using the label wrong and you could easilly solve your problem by using either if .. if else and else statements or use the switch statement.

Comment: Sean and Peter are correct: labels work with *loops only.*  Not `if` statements like the OP has and not other code blocks.  As Sean mentions, it's easy to break out of an `if` if you just structure it properly.